# Is it good idea to redirect (301) domain+links without "Address Change" in Google Webmaster?

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

Lets say, I want to move most of my site content from `example.com` to `a1.com`, but also want to put i.e. 20 pages to `a2.com`.
Mainly I care about page-rank to be transited well.

what are best way to do that? Should I use `Address Change` tool in webmaster and  `.htaccess` 301 redirect everything to `a1.com` (except those 20 links- redirect them to `a2.com`)

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **change of address tool** is meant to move the whole domain to a new domain or subdomain. First you need to setup the `301 redirects` and then let Google know about the change of URL through this tool.

In your case, I'll not recommend using the change of address tool cause you can get Google Bot confused: you are changing to a new domain but at the same time you are redirecting some URLs to another domain.

Check [Google official guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en):

> Don't chain site moves. If you submit a change of address to redirect traffic from site A to site B, you can't immediately submit another change of address from site B to site C.

I'll use 301 redirects and updated sitemaps for each new domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about page rank transfer for each page then it's best to do page wise 301 for the relevant pages on the new website. This way you will keep the page relevancy.

You should also do homepage to homepage 301 to transfer the power of root document.

Finally make sure google crawls find the redirect.